# htaccess: always redirect to www with subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry that i'm new on htaccess and have a issue now.

I was able be redirect from domain.com/admin to www.domain.com/admin

But failed with domain.com/test which bring me back to www.domain.com, and it's fine if i go in with fullname www.domain.com/test

Both /admin and /test are valid subdirectory, only different is /admin doesn't have htaccess file but /test do have

this is my home htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page_process.php
```

And this is subdirectory /test htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/page_process.php
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the htaccess in the root directory :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page_process.php
```

And this code for the htaccess in the test directory :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page_process.php
```